# Exposing web application hosted in Azure Kubernetes container to inside organization and to external world

Tags: azure, kubernetes

I have web application hosted as linux container in Azure Kubernetes Service. I am using Azure Application Gateway Ingress controller. I tried to expose this web application using Azure API Gateway service however it is not working as expected. Only first url get loaded but subsequent requests to other resources i.e. css, js etc fails. Since API Gateway is not meant for web applications what are my other options that I could use to expose this web application hosted in AKS?
I want to use Azure AD to authenticate users on this application. Any pointers would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I would say the ingress rules need to be configured of type `prefix` instead of `exact match`. This will ensure that all the

1. Requests for `/some/endpoint/`
2. And for `/some/endpoint/*`

will both be served by the same backend service.

Therefore, for all resources, the endpoint would function correctly. It is definitely possible to host a web application with an Ingress :)

Comment: I have Azure App GW ingress controller configuration with "Prefix" path in place and works perfectly however I have App GW--> API GW (configured in internal mode)  --> Ingress controller --> AKS. Once I expose app on my App GW which is entry point things starts failing as request for landing page works fine but dependent sources of landing page like css, js, images urls roots at App GW hostname. Any suggestion?

Comment: I think [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/create-url-route-portal) documentation page might help. It provides a functioning example of how to configure the App GW to have URL based routing.